# How to get Frame().camera ARCore

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

I am trying to place an anchor straight in front of the camera 1m away.

I found a code to make this.

```
mAnchors.add(session.createAnchor(
frame.getCamera().getPose()
    .compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -1f))
    .extractTranslation()))
```

My code looks like below:

```
val anchor =Session(this).createAnchor(
Frame().camera.pose.compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0f,0f,-1f)))
```

The problem is Frame() constructor. Compilier comes with error:

> "Cannot acces '': it is protected/*protected and package*/ in
>   Frame'

Is any way to initialize Frame().camera or I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't initialize the frame. You`re getting it from the session

you do it something like this way

@Override

```
  public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    // Clear screen to notify driver it should not load any pixels from previous frame.

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



    if (session == null) {

      return;

    }

    // Notify ARCore session that the view size changed so that the perspective matrix and

    // the video background can be properly adjusted.

    displayRotationHelper.updateSessionIfNeeded(session);



    try {

      session.setCameraTextureName(backgroundRenderer.getTextureId());



      // Obtain the current frame from ARSession. When the configuration is set to

      // UpdateMode.BLOCKING (it is by default), this will throttle the rendering to the

      // camera framerate.

      Frame frame = session.update();
    } catch (Throwable t) {

      // Avoid crashing the application due to unhandled exceptions.

      Log.e(TAG, "Exception on the OpenGL thread", t);

    }
}
```